# KeyListener always gives me an error when trying to add it to my JFrame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, graphics, keylistener

Every time I try to add my separate class that holds all of my key inputs to my JFrame, Eclipse tells me to do this: `frame.add(frame, new KeyInput());`, which returns the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself
```

. I understand this error and where it came from:

```
frame.add(frame, new KeyInput());
          ^^^^^
```

, but if I take the frame component out, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (KeyInput)
```

This one I don't understand, but get the gist: Eclipse caught an actual error.

Comment: Why are you trying to add a component to itself? I would consider having a closer look at the API documentation for the `add` method.  I would also consider having a look at the [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API as an alternative to `KeyListener`, as it solves the primary focus related issues

Comment: @MadProgrammer as I mentioned, without the component, and frame is the only one I have, I get an error. And I have already looked at the Key Bindings API, and I have no clue how to use them.

Comment: The question still remains, why are you trying to add a component to itself? It's makes no sense and, as Java is telling, it's an illegal operation - Have you read through [How to write a key listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)?

Comment: My "general" recommendation would be to take a step back.  Start by basing your GUI on a `JPanel`. When you're ready, create an instance of `JFrame` and add an instance of your GUI (`JPanel`) to it - it will simply many of the issues associated with dealing with a `JFrame` directly - *"And I have already looked at the Key Bindings API, and I have no clue how to use them"* - So, here's an opportunity to learn, there are plenty of examples available and it will prevent you from having to post a new question about why your `KeyListener` randomly stops working

Comment: The underlying issue is, this is NOT how you apply `KeyListener` to a component

Comment: MadProgrammer is correct, use `frame.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter(......));` instead of `frame.add(frame, new KeyInput());`

Comment: @sorifiend what goes inside your `(.........)`?? I have never used your method.

Comment: @B.Polk see the answer from MadProgrammer below for more info, but you just need in create a KeyAdapter there, here is an example for a key pressed listener: `frame.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter()
        {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)
            {
                do_Something_Here;
            }
        });`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I figured out my problem. See the new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming** that `KeyInput` is an instance of a `KeyListener`, then you "should" be using `addKeyListener` defined in [`java.awt.Component`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addKeyListener-java.awt.event.KeyListener-) (which [`javax.swing.JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) inherits from)

This is further outlined in [How to write key listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

However, there are any number of issues which could result from doing this.  Because you're adding the listener to the base frame, you're ignoring the fact that there are a number components between it and the user, all of which could consume the event or steal focus

[image: JRootPane]

`KeyListener` will only respond to key events when the component it is registered to:

- is focusable
- and has keyboard focus

This means that other components which also respond to keyboard input can steal the keyboard focus and your listener will no longer be triggered. This is a very common issue with `KeyListener` which has been resolved through the [Key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)